# I'm comparing multiple demographics across multiple samples, Chi-square test or 2 sample t-test

Tags: proportion, z-test, demography

I would like to compare the demographics of people my company serves with the demographics contained in a subset of the American Community Survey 2017 data. The first set (n=35751) of data is a person-level roster of company clients as rows and demographic info as columns. The second set (n=19316) is ACS data filtered for my county and further cleaned for analysis.

I want to run hypothesis tests like the following:

1. The proportion of black people served by my company is statistically equal to proportion of black people in my company's county.
2. The proportion of Asian people served by my company is less than the proportion of Asian people in my company's county.

My racial data is Boolean for each race so a single individual can have multiple races. Here's and example of the first few columns/rows. There is an additional column to differentiate whether the data is from my company or from the ACS.

```
       RACE_ASIAN  RACE_BLACK  RACE_NATIVE_AMERICAN      SOURCE  \...
0             0.0         0.0                   1.0     company 
1             0.0         1.0                   1.0     company   
2             1.0         1.0                   0.0         acs   
3             0.0         1.0                   0.0         acs   
4             0.0         1.0                   0.0     company   
5             1.0         0.0                   1.0         acs
```

I thought about using a Chi-Square Test of Independence with races as columns and sources as rows would work but that requires each response to be represented once on the contingency table. To accomplish this I would need to concatenate the race labels for each respondent (eg., Black&WHITE, ASIAN&BLACK, WHITE&ASIAN&PACIFIC_ISLANDER, etc) and that would not grow into a long list but I might not be able to get 5 people in each racial bucket.

My next thought is to conduct a two-sided, two-proportion Z test for each of the racial categories where the two proportions are each source. I'm using Python to accomplish this so I would probably get my counts, totals, and proportion in a table and iterate through it comparing same races.

Would you go with the two-sided, two-proportion Z test or is there another test you would use?

Comment: "not be able to get 5 people in each racial bucket" Where does this come from, given you have so many people in the sample?

Comment: @user158565, now that you mention this I figured it might be worth a shot to convert the 1's to race_label and 0's to not race_label and concatenate the values for each response. Then I can see if I can meet the assumption of >5 in a bucket.

Comment: Try Fisher's exact test first, which is best. If Fisher's exact test takes too long time, use Pearson Chi-square test. Given long time for Fisher's exact test, the requirement for frequency in each cell by Chi-square test should be met.

Comment: @user158565 what about one response (Black and Native American) being in two buckets? what if someone has multiple races selected?

Comment: Given you just interesting on black and Asian, you need to create a new variable such that each person can just take one of the three values: black, Asian and other.